# Print tensor only after initialised and feed it with some value

Tags: tensorflow

After reading thousands of tutorials I am not still able to print tensors values in some scenario. What is clear to me is that tensorflow first builds the graph and then it actually feeds the values of variables, placeholders etc. However, I am not able to print the values of some tensor in this code [link_1](https://github.com/mxl456/pTransE). More details below.

The `_build_train()` function is defined as following (line 156 of `ptranse.py`), and it calls the `_forward_t_model` method in order to return the `t_z_pos` and `t_z_neg` tensors.

```python
def _build_train(self):
    t_z_pos, t_z_neg = self._forward_t_model(self._w, self._v, False)
    at_z_pos, at_z_neg = self._forward_t_model(self._aw, self._av, True)
    k_z_pos, k_z_h_neg, k_z_t_neg, k_z_r_neg = self._forward_k_model(self._pos_h, self._pos_t, self._pos_r)
    ak_z_pos, ak_z_h_neg, ak_z_t_neg, ak_z_r_neg = self._forward_k_model(self._pos_ah, self._pos_at, self._pos_ar)
    nce_loss = self._nce_loss(t_z_pos, t_z_neg, k_z_pos, k_z_h_neg, k_z_t_neg, k_z_r_neg)
    nce_loss = nce_loss + self._nce_loss(at_z_pos, at_z_neg, ak_z_pos, ak_z_h_neg, ak_z_t_neg, ak_z_r_neg)
    self._train = self._optimize(nce_loss)
    self._loss = nce_loss
```

I am interested in printing  `t_z_pos` and `t_z_neg` values and as suggested here [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633370/how-to-print-the-value-of-a-tensor-object-in-tensorflow) I have added after `t_z_pos, t_z_neg = self._forward_t_model(self._w, self._v, False)` the following line:

```
print(t_z_pos.eval())
```

However, the execution stops by showing the following message: `You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'w_' with dtype int32 and shape [64]...`

I guess that the script crashes because I am asking to print a value while it is still building the graph (so before feeding the tensors with some values). My question is, how can I print the values of tensors just after they have been initialised and feed with some value? There are similar questions for my same problem [link_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607155/you-must-feed-a-value-for-placeholder-tensor-placeholder-with-dtype-float), [link_4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243194/tensorflow-feed-dict-error-you-must-feed-a-value-for-placeholder-tensor) and [link_5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183060/placeholder-tensor-issue-you-must-feed-a-value-for-placeholder-tensor-placehol) but none of them helped me to figure this out.

Comment: Please make your question concise and self-contained. We should not need to search through numerous external links.

Comment: I have edited the question.